# I don't understand some old C array concatenation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memcpy

I don't understand this syntax in this old `C` program, and am not set up to test the code to see what it does. The part I am confused about is the concatenation to the array. I didn't think C could handle auto-typecasting like that, or am I making it too difficult in my head being that its Friday afternoon...

```
char wrkbuf[1024];
int r;
//Some other code
//Below, Vrec is a 4 byte struct
memcpy( &Vrec, wrkbuf + r, 4 );
```

Any idea what will happen here?  What does `wrkbuf` become when you concatenate or add an int to it?

Answer (score 4):

`wrkbuf + r` is the same as `&wrkbuf[r]`

Essentially `wrkbuf` when used as in the expression `wrkbuf + 4` "decays" into a pointer to the first element. You then add `r` to it, which advances the pointer by `r` elements. i.e. there's no concatenation going on here, it's doing pointer arithmetic.

The `memcpy( &Vrec, wrkbuf + r, 4 );` copies 4 bytes from the wrkbuf array , starting at the `r`th element into the memory space of `Vrec`

Comment: Isn't that exactly backwards?  You're copying into `&Vrec`.  `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy(&Vrec, wrkbuf + r, 4)` copies 4 bytes from the `r`-th position of `wrkbuf` into `Vrec`. When you add an int to an array, you get the memory addresss of the `r`-th position of it, in this case, `&wrkbuf[r]`.

Sample `memcpy` C implementation (as you can see, it is quite similar to `strcpy`):

```
void *
memcpy (void *destaddr, void const *srcaddr, size_t len)
{
  char *dest = destaddr;
  char const *src = srcaddr;

  while (len-- > 0)
    *dest++ = *src++;
  return destaddr;
}
```

#### See:

- [memcpy man page](http://www.manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/unix/freebsd-6.2/3/memcpy-man-page.html)